# I have forgotten sql server sa password and I cannot connect with windows auth. How can I reset sql server password?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have got only admin role windows login.
How can I reset sql server password?

Comment: [Dupe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4679/97345).

Comment: The password is "1234"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out).

This describes how to regain access to a SQL server when locked out of it.

Comment: That's it.Thank you.